# Android: BitmapFactory issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gridview

Good Day 
I'm trying to display captured image in gridview as well save it in Sqlite Database..in the logcat appear this

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException W/System.err:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException W/System.err:  at
>   .CameraFragment.previewCapturedImage(CameraFragment.java:259
>   W/System.err:  at
>   CameraFragment.onActivityResult(CameraFragment.java:215)

**which point to this line in my code**

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
```

**here is the code**

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

            final DatabaseAdapter DBadapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
            DBadapter.open();
            myLists = new ArrayList<Images>();
            myLists = DBadapter.getImagesList();
            // imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageListView);
            Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   // fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);// create a file to save the image
                   // intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE); // start the image capture Intent


                }
            });
            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.img_list_view, myLists);
            myGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            myGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
        }


        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE&&resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                           previewCapturedImage();

                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "InvoiceFile saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                       else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                           // user cancelled Image capture
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                   .show();}
                       else {
                           // failed to capture image

                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                   .show();
                       }}
         private void previewCapturedImage() {


        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);

                    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                    images.setImageBlob(byte_arr);
                    // Add Image Path To List
                    myLists.add(images);
                    // Refresh Gridview Image Thumbnails

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    DBadapter.insertImage(images);

                }
```

**any Help will be appreciate**

Comment: check if BitmapFactory.decodeFile() returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts)` returns `null` for you. From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) about return value:

> The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)

First, check the `mCurrentPhotoPath` value, if photo is there and it is correct.
Second, try to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName)` instead.

Comment: i check mCurrentPhotoPath value it's return null i don't know why @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: I cannot get answer from this piece of code, show more.

Comment: From this code impossible to have `mCurrentPhotoPath == null`. Check another places where you changing it. Second note, `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` accept file path, not URI, why `file` prefix is there?

Comment: i check mCurrentPath value again by display it in the logcat..it's return a value but in the onActivityResult() after i capture the image it goes to **else Statement**  _"Sorry! Failed to capture image"_ why? @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: Log `requestCode` and `resultCode` also to see why.

Comment: Guess, `requestCode` doesn't equal to `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE`.

Comment: `requestCode`= 1 and `resultCode`=-1 and `CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE`=100 @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: maybe.because it's in Fragment?

Comment: No, doesn't matter if it is Fragment. If your `onActivityResult` proceed only result from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you could remove `requestCode` check to have it simply.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me.If you need more details http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/02/multiple-choose-custom-gallery.html

```
 if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { imageUri.getPath() }, null,
               new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
               Log.i("Scanned = ", "Scanned " + path);
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 //UI Works
                 loadData();
                }
               });
   }
     });
```